# Apple Pay - get full shipping address (containing 'addressLines')

Tags: javascript, braintree, applepayjs

I'm doing an **Apple Pay WEB integration** (using **JS**) and Braintree as a payment provider.

I  need to calculate some taxes (**US sales tax)** for the order.
Current flow: The user clicks *Pay with Apple Pay* button, the Apple Pay payment sheet is displayed (we require **shipping address** containing the *postal address,zipcode,name and email*).

After that the payment sheet is displayed -> I call the **session.onshippingcontactselected** function, but at this point I can only get the *locality,administrativeArea,postalCode,country* and *countryCode* values from the shippingContact, so I'm not getting the **addressLines** containing the **street name** and its **number**. I need these values as well to accurately calculate my tax.

I know that Apple says in docs that they only provide the full address after the user authorizes the payment, meaning after the payment was done (this is too late for me, cause I need to know the tax amount before the order is being placed/before the user authorizes/pays the order).

Is there a workaround through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

As this information is delivered by Apple directly, there isn't a means by which you could circumvent the redacted [`shippingContact`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/payment/1916097-shippingcontact) information provided in the pre-authorized session using Braintree's integration. If you need the full address to calculate tax you'd need to collect that from your customer earlier in the payment process or use a different means to calculate tax using the information provided in the `shippingContact` object. I'd recommend sending our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) an email to discuss this further.

Comment: Thanks :). I'm eventually using as much as I can get from the shipping contact and estimate the amount at least.It's true, I can get the full address only after the user authorizes the payment.